# Why don't Perl commands work after I run `plenv local system`?

Tags: perl, shell, plenv

On a CentOS 6.5 machine, I have two versions of perl installed through plenv.

When I am running perl 5.8.8, I can run any perl command fine in the shell such as

```
plenv local 5.8.8
perl -e "print 'hello';"
hello
```

But When I switch to alias "system"

```
plenv local system
perl -e "print 'hello';"
```

The command doesn't execute and feeds into a new line as if the perl command is waiting for input. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> doesn't end input, either.

So my questions are,

- is this an old perl behavior?
- How do I check the version of an alias perl? (typing `perl -v` doesn't execute, as I described above)

**update:**
Results to commands requested in comments

```
$: plenv version 
system (set by /home/myuser/.perl-version) 
$: type perl 
perl is hashed (/opt/plenv/shims/perl) 
$: plenv local 5.8.8 
$: plenv version 
5.8.8 (set by /home/myuser/.perl-version) 
$: type perl 
perl is hashed (/opt/plenv/shims/perl)
```

Comment: If `perl -v` doesn't work, then there is something wrong with that perl.

Comment: No, this command would have worked at least back to early Perl 4, and probably much longer. What's the output of `type perl`?

Comment: Also interested in `type perl`'s output

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this website and can't figure out the formatting in the comment section

Comment: Adding to the question is the right thing to do. /// Oh, `plenv` doesn't work through PATH manipulations? I guess the next thing to do is study `/opt/plenv/shims/perl` /// Tag users e.g. using `@ikegami` so they notified of the comment.

Comment: plenv is better than perlbrew in that sense (no path mangling).

Comment: @Сухой27, I don't see how avoid PATH manipulations is better (or worse)

Comment: So the concensus is that the perl is corrupt? Or as @ikegami mentioned, I'm missing something about /opt/plenv/shims/perl?

Comment: Re "*So the concensus is that the perl is corrupt?*", Hell no. If a Perl interpreter is being run at all, it's likely being run with no arguments. Determining which of these is true requires finding out what `/opt/plenv/shims/perl` executes and how.

Comment: Actually, you could just use `echo 'print "hello";' | perl`. If it works, a Perl interpreter is being called, but no arguments were passed to it.

Comment: With plenv you can define perl version per project directory, and not to worry about manual version switching.